# About determining if the user is the owner of the file in C

Tags: c, terminal

Just want to make sure if I'm right about this, would it be justified to say that for some:

```
struct stat fStat;
```

given that the argument passed in the terminal will be either a file or directory, can I state that

```
if((fileStat.st_mode & S_IRWXU) == true)
```

then the user is also the owner of the file? What about if I'm checking a directory outside of the directory I'm currently in, would this still hold valid?(granted that it's correct) 
New to all this, an explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure for this method. But implementation depends on operation system and file system you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All that confirms is that the file has certain permissions for the owner, it does not state that you are actually the owner.

There's another field in the `stat` structure called `st_uid` which is the user ID of the owner. You need to compare that against your own user ID (see the `getuid()` function).